# Fast data read / write methods embedded into VB .NET program

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, sqlite

Currently I have been working on a program that has grown much bigger than I originally thought. I save the data that it generates to text files and then read from those when the data is needed or upon launching the program.. This is quite slow of course once the data gets to a large size.

I know setting up a SQL server is a good, efficient way to store data usually but I want my application to be "self contained", meaning it doesn't need to be on a network to work (so that rules out SQL). I have read up a little bit on SQLLITE which seems better but still requires the user to install something, rather than just run my program so it isn't "self contained". I want to know if anyone else has found something that can be embedded into the solution?  My idea is that all the data would still reside in a file that contains the database and is built upon build or some sort of events from the program.

I hope what I am asking makes sense. Basically I just want to avoid the user from having to install anything and if I copy my program and the "database files" to another computer, it will work without problems.

Comment: Dont rule out still more future like concurrent, networked users, web access.  The nature of the data and expected use case should be more important than no-server.

Comment: Due to the environment I work in I am unable to host an actual server due to security here at my work being why I want to keep it local to each user.

Comment: Use SqlLite users more than likely don't need to install anything...

Comment: @zaggler Can you transfer your data easily like I asked above? can the database be transferred just by copying a file over? I apologize but I haven't used SQLLITE before.

Comment: Sure you can, I've used it before on projects and works just fine for what I was doing. Read the use cases here http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

Comment: @zaggler so does the actual data live in a separate file or within the .exe file itself for my case of a standalone application?

Comment: In a file outside of the exe. Its self-contained, zero configuration etc... SQLite reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files. A complete SQL database with multiple tables, indices, triggers, and views, is contained in a single disk file.

Comment: @zaggler Awesome that sounds like exactly what I am asking for! Thanks for your advice / help. If you want to answer as an actual answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: If you like to use MS Sql in general, you can also use [Sql Compact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142). I think it is also stand alone, similar to SQLite.  It supports Entity Framework as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I have read up a little bit on SQLLITE which seems better but still requires the user to install something**

User's typically ***do not*** need to install anything as it's a stand-alone...

[**SQLite features**](http://www.sqlite.org/features.html) are robust and would suit saving and retrieving your data back. SQLite reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files. A complete SQL database with multiple tables, indices, triggers, and views, is contained in a single disk file.

To read more please [see uses](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) in which this explains more in detail.